# When running the app my buttons dont seem to work?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    //This will set a 3 second delay before the app opens
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }, 5000);
}

char initial;
int space, engineSize;
double miles, rate;
String Combined, fullName; //Global Variables

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.enterEmployeeDetails: //When this button is pressed it will change the layout to the activity_get_name

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_name); //When "Enter Employee Details" is pressed it changes to the activity_get_name layout
            //This will show the activity_get_name layout
            break;

        case R.id.switchButton: //When this button is pressed it will store the inputted name

            EditText fName = findViewById(R.id.fullName); //This will store the input value

            String fullName = fName.getText().toString();

            space = fullName.indexOf(" ");
            initial = fullName.charAt(0);
            String last = fullName.substring(space);

            Combined = (initial + last);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_expenses); //This will show the layout activity_get_expenses

            break;

        case R.id.continueProcessing: //When this button is pressed it will change the layout to activity_display

            EditText engSize = findViewById(R.id.engineCcTxt); //This will store the input value
            try { //This will start a try-catch routine
                engineSize = Integer.parseInt(engSize.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_expenses);
                break;
            }

            EditText Distance = findViewById(R.id.miles); //This will store the input value
            try {
                miles = Double.parseDouble(Distance.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_expenses);
                break;
            }

            if (miles < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a positive number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_expenses);
                break;
            }

            double calcuRate = calcRate(engineSize);
            double expDue = calcuRate * miles; //This will workout the Expenses due

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display); //This will change the layout to activity_display

            TextView empName = findViewById(R.id.displayNameTxt);
            empName.setText(Combined); //This will output the Employee name

            TextView engine = findViewById(R.id.displayEngineTxt);
            engine.setText(Double.toString(engineSize)); //This will output the size of the engine

            TextView milAge = findViewById(R.id.displayMilesTxt);
            milAge.setText(Double.toString(miles)); //This will output the distance travelled

            TextView CalRate = findViewById(R.id.displayRateTxt);
            CalRate.setText("£" + Double.toString(calcuRate)); //This will output the mileage rate

            TextView expen = findViewById(R.id.displayExpensesTxt);
            expen.setText("£" + Double.toString(expDue)); //This will output the Expenses due

            break;

        case R.id.exitButton: //When this button is pressed it will show a splash screen

            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
            //This will set a 3 second delay before the app exits
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //This will close the app
                    finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
            break;
        case R.id.returnButton: //When this button is pressed it will go back at the start
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            break;

    }
}

public double calcRate(double size) { //This will calculate the milage rate
    if (size < 1100) {
        rate = 0.64;
    } else if (size <= 2000) {
        rate = 0.72;
    } else rate = 0.79;

    return (rate);
}
```

**The code is for a computing project at college, so I am a complete amatuer when it comes to this. The code is supposed to switch to the other page so all the inputs can be filled in and then display all the data and calculations at the end however it doesnt seem to work despite there being no erros and neither buttons appear to work at all.**

Comment: use `startActivity(intent)` instead of setting a new layout for the same activity.

Comment: Did you call `View.setOnClickListener()`?

Answer (score 0):

First Create Instance of your Button in onCreate() and use setOnClickListener()

```
Button switchButton = findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
switchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```